# PDF Forms designer

Tags: forms, pdf, designer

I'm trying to create a java report from a java web application using a tool names **PDF forms designer** , it generates a pdf file from a dynamic design , i want to know how can i open the pdf on the browser and gather all the information from the field of the form ? does any one know how to use this tool